# Is there a way to reorder the records in Realm Studio?

Tags: realm-database

I am using a Realm database in an iOS app and utilize Realm Studio (RS) to manage the data. Is there a way to reorder record order in Realm Studio, or delete a record?

Thanks.
Blessings,
—Mark

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the current version (2.4.1) supports reordering.

Deleting objects in Realm Studio is possible. You can right-click on an object and choose "Delete selected object". You can select multiple objects with shift or command key and delete them all at once too.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info!